# How can I write array of coordinates to Cloud Firestore

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

How can I write an array of coordinates to the Cloud Firestore as a `GeoPoint` datatype?

I do have an `arraylist<latlng> points` with coordinates and I need to write those coordinates to Firestore:

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    mLastLocation = location;

    mLatLng = new 
LatLng(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude());
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(mLatLng));

    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(20));

    if (mDraw) {
        points.add(mLatLng); //added
        drawPolyLine();
    }


}

private void drawPolyLine(){
    mMap.clear();

    PolylineOptions options = new 
PolylineOptions().width(5).color(Color.BLUE).geodesic(true);
    for (int i = 0; i < points.size(); i++) {
        LatLng point = points.get(i);
        options.add(point);
    }

    line = mMap.addPolyline(options); //add Polyline
}
```

What I tried `docRef.update("Test", FieldValue.arrayUnion(points));` and `docRef.set(points);` both resulted in errors `Nested arrays not supported` and `required map String or related POJO respectively`.

Comment: What have you tried? I cannot see in your code anything related to adding data in Firestore.

Comment: sorry for the late replay. i tried `docRef.update("Test", FieldValue.arrayUnion(points));` and `docRef.set(points);`.

Comment: both resulted in errors `Nested arrays not supported` and `required map String or related POJO`  respectively

Comment: That's because you are storing arrays inside arrays

Comment: Yes, so how can i store the nested arrays to firestore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When passing [FieldValue.arrayUnion](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/firebase/firestore/FieldValue.html#arrayUnion(java.lang.Object...)) as the second argument to the [update()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentReference.html#update(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object...)) method like in the the following line of code:

```
docRef.update("Test", FieldValue.arrayUnion(points));
```

It means that you are telling Firebase that you want to update a property within a document which is of type `array` with a `List`, which is actually not possible, hence this error:

```
Nested arrays not supported
```

If you have documents that contain nested arrays, please note that a regular update is currently not possible. What can you do instead is to get the entire document and call [getData()](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentSnapshot.html#getData()) on the `DocumentSnapshot` object. The type of object that is returned is a `Map<String, Object>`. Iterate through the map, update the desired value and write the document back in the database.

Comment: I cannot write code for you, I just described the mechanism. So you should make your own attempt given the information in the answer and ask another question if something else comes up.

Comment: Ok, i will do what i can and let you know

Comment: Perfect, keep me poested.

Answer (score 1):

You can write your coordinates in cloud firestore like this

```
    Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
     map.put("coordinates", Arrays.asList(points));

     db.collection("REFERENCE").document("mDocumentId")
            .update(map);
```

Comment: this returns the same error as mentioned above `nested arrays not supported`